# How to insert binary data into the database using Sqlite3 in Python?

Tags: sql, sqlite, ipython

How to insert binary data into the database using Sqlite3 in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#introduction), blobs require using a `buffer` object:

```
blob = buffer('data...')
db.execute("INSERT INTO tab(blob) VALUES(?)", [blob]
```